# Online travel agency does not answer my messages about refunding my cancelled flights

Tags: covid-19, airlines, refunds, communication, travel-agency

I booked quite a few flights in 2020 that got cancelled because of the travel restrictions of the pandemic. The travel agency (quite a known one on the internet) had two options for the refund:

- faster refund – I would pay $20 or so and they would make process faster (up to 3 months)
- normal refund workflow – up to 6 months

I chose the faster refund and paid $20 more. The refund is still in process, but they do not answer me anymore to my messages.

I tried to be as friendly as possible, because I realize that we are going together through all this crazy time and I imagine that they had a lot of flights to get refunds from.

However, they do not answer me anymore to my messages at all. It has been about 20 months since the flights got cancelled, and about 6 months since they just don't answer me at all anymore.

---

I tried contacting the airlines directly and the result was:

- got a refund from `company A`
- got an ecredit from `company B`
- `company C` told me that only the travel agency can get the refund and not me directly
- `company D` told me to write an email to `refunds@...` and then I have not got any response anymore.

---

Is there anything I can do to make them answer my emails/calls?

Being old cancelled flights, they are not answering me via phone, but only a bot. They do not reply via email. At this point, I do not even care that much for the money (it would be nice to get it back), but I am a bit disapointed with the companies' behavior...

Comment: Did you pay with a credit card ?

Comment: We're probably going to need to review the rules of the company. I know you're not wanting to out them, but you really should.

Comment: @CGCampbell Can I do that here on this site? I didn't want the question to look like a rant against those companies/airlines. I can add that info if it helps.

Comment: The best route would be filing a dispute with your credit card and getting the money much faster than 3 or 6 months that way, but I suspect now is too late for that.... Unfortunately when you buy cheap tickets from a travel agency you also take the risk of dealing with that agency if something goes wrong. They're not earning anything from you, so they have no incentive to actually do anything. What can you do, sue them?

Comment: Be aware ALL airlines/OTAs are swamped at present (have been for over a year). Iv'e seen calls to Qantas with people on hold for 7-12 hours!

Comment: @MarkMayo I totally understand they are busy, but are they _that_ busy to not reply my messages sent in September and October...? One of the airlines just confirmed me they refunded the flight value last year in April, but I cannot find the refund in my bank -- perhaps they refunded it into the agency bank account...

Comment: @IonicăBizău that is potentially the reason - refund may need to work down the pipeline. Still pretty crappy tho :/

Comment: @MarkMayo Today I sent them another notification message via Twitter, Facebook, and Support desk messages... On their Instagram all people are pretty much complaining about the same thing and it seems they respond them in the comments...

Comment: Just a quick update: they confirmed they received the refunds of my flights, but they are refunding the clients in chronological order... Starting with those who were waiting before me...